# Steam Error: Access Denied

Tags: php, curl, steam, steambot

I have a problem with trades. My steam bot send many trades and they sending good, but sometimes I saw the error (all requests I do from https to https):

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD> 
        <TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE> 
    </HEAD>
    <BODY> 
        <H1>Access Denied</H1> 
        You don't have permission to access "http://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/send" on this server.
        <P> Reference ....... 
    </BODY> 
</HTML>
```

What does mean and how I can fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you solved your problem but if not I may help.
Access denied for using steam API or bot, usually means you haven't deposited the 5 bucks into the account then its limited.

Answer (score 2):

You need an authentification.

Provide partner and token in URL, or sessionid (if you have) by cookie

`https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=".$usersid32."&token=".$token`

https://www.reddit.com/r/SteamBot/comments/3difg0/unable_to_send_trade_offer_receiving_error_401/

Comment: But i authentificated, and i provide all data. I have mentioned that many trades are successful, but some of them receiving an error

Comment: May be your session have expired.

Comment: No, bot login 1-2 minutes ago(